# Ordering Server adding sshkeys

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to order server with sshkeys using the api, but when I use the sshkey property in the structure it returns the result without the keys, I know my code is working fine becausw I orderwd before. I would like to check if my ids are correct, is there any form to check them by using my label names???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the structure for ssh keys:

```
 "sshKeys": [
        {
            "sshKeyIds": [94206]
        }
]
```

You can call http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getSshKeys method to get the IDs of your sshs keys and you can use object filters to get the ssks by label this is am example using Rest:

```
GET https://<USERNAME>:<APIKEY>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getSshKeys?objectFilter={"sshKeys":{"label":{"operation":"tonny"}}}
```

here more information about object filters http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn´t work out at first, I used the method and worked great! but apparently in the structure the brackets should be taken out and send the id only. Thanks a lot Raul!!, I will try the filter and let you know.